# Centering HTML tables and text in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I know that Jupyter is using it's own CSS style which limits what you can do with HTML unless you edit it.

I try to display some info with more sophisticated way than Python `print` and for that I use:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML('<center>some header text</center>')))
```

Everything is left aligned though - both text and tables. Is there any simple workaround for this?

Or is there any other way to have centered tables in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to use a small bit of custom CSS in your html elements. The important bit is `style='margin: 0 auto'` For example:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("""
<table style='margin: 0 auto'>
<tr><th>Hi!</th><th>There!</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
"""))
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks! That's correct. I've just found out moment ago. Also I recommend this blogpost for anyone who has similar problems: http://blog.booleanbiotech.com/ipython_notebook_tips.html